# Inverse function theorem question - multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse

This is an exercise in Inverse Function Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

we are given the function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$

1) Show that $f$ is injective around every point in $\mathbb R^2$ - I managed to solve this

2) Find environments around the points $(0,\pi)$ and $(-1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $f$ is injective in those environments, and find the inverse function in those environments

I managed to do question number 1, but am stumped by question number 2.

The answer to question 1 is that the determinant of the Jacobi matrix is $e^{2x}$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and that is always positive and so the determinant in every point on the plane is different than zero, and so we can apply inverse function theorem.

Question number 2...Could use a hand

Comment: I take it that with *environments* you mean *neighborhoods*.

Comment: Yes thank you...English is not my native tongue. I do apologize.

Comment: If you can solve 1., then 2. follows easily. In 1. you proved that $f$ is injective around every point, so take as a neighborhood for 2. one of the neighborhoods in which you proved that $f$ is injective in 1.

Comment: But I did not find such neighborhood. I just said "There's a neighborhood around every point". I don't know how to find said neighborhood.

Comment: How did you prove such a neighborhood exists?

Comment: It follows from inverse function theorem. "For functions of a single variable, the theorem states that if ƒ is a continuously differentiable function with nonzero derivative at the point a, then ƒ is invertible in a neighborhood of a". I just showed $f$ meets the demands for the theorem. It's still invertible even not for single variable.

Comment: I see. Can you go further with the only answer given as of now?

Comment: The Jacobi Determinant would become $e^{2x},$ so we have to choose x in the given interval such that determinant never vanishes. which will imply there there is neighborhood within which it's injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we write 
\begin{cases}u&=&e^x\cos y\\ v&=&e^x\sin y\end{cases}
so that $f(x,y)=(u,v)$.

Can you solve that system of equations for x and y?
If so, what are the conditions for the solution to be a valid inverse around the points you mentioned?

Comment: I get $x=\frac{1}{2}ln(u^2+v^2)$ and $y=arccos(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}})$ is this correct? How does this help?

Comment: Good! However, it should be $y=\pm\arccos\left(\frac u {\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\right) + 2k\pi \ (k \in \mathbb Z)$. As you can see, it is not defined for u=v=0 only, and furthermore there are multiple solutions for y. For your problem you have to selection 1 of those solutions and pick neighborhoods that in particular exclude (u,v)=(0,0).

Comment: And how will we find the inverse?

Comment: Huh? This *is* the inverse.

Comment: That is ofcourse correct. Thank you friend.